# MethodInfo.Invoke Throw TargetInvocationException c#

Tags: c#, invoke, methodinfo, targetinvocationexception

So here is my problem with a TargetInvocationException.

This error occurs on a line with a `MethodInfo method.Invoke(null, arguments);`

FYI I'm working on a code someone made before me, in 2014, it was supposed to work but it's not. After searching during the whole week end, I didn't find the problem.
Don't hesitate to ask me for more informations about the code I have, maybe the problem comes from somewhere else.

In the main program it's look like this ( there is not all the code, some parts are between those lines, but you don't need them ):

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
    [... Code before]
    object[] arguments = { popup };
    MethodInfo method;
    CodeCompiler cc = new CodeCompiler();
    method = cc.CompileCode(fichier, "test", "RequestWeb", "requestW", true, arguments);

    List<Account> li = (List<Account>)method.Invoke(null, arguments); // TargetInvocationException Here is the error
}
```

And here is the class Account :

```
public class Account
{
    virtual public string libelle { get; set; }
    virtual public List<AccountStat> listR { get; set; }

    public Account()
    {
        this.listR = new List<AccountStat>(); // This go to another class where List<AccountStat> is defined
    }
}
```

I tried to understand with the InnerException system who tell me :

"The index was off limits. It should not be negative and must be less than the size of the collection \ r \ nName parameter . StartIndex"

but I still don't understand what it mean... Is the problem with `List<Account>` ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since it seems you're debugging code compiled on-the-fly, I'm going to assume you have no debugging information. You'll have to manually comb through the dynamically compiled code to see where the `IndexOutOfRangeException` can possibly happen, and use old-school debugging techniques to narrow it down (e.g. `Debug.WriteLine` at useful places).

Comment: what do you get at `method`?

Comment: `CodeCompiler` is an abstract class. How come you create an instance of it? Are you not targeting `System.CodeDom.Compiler` namespace?

Comment: Luaan : I will try with Debug.WriteLine to see where it comes exactly. For the moment I m trying to see if the problem do not comes from the `method`. 

Amit Kumar Ghosh : At `method` I get my dynamic compilation ( which works totally ) from my `public MethodInfo CompileCode(string code, string namespacename, string classname,string functionname, bool isstatic, params object[] args)` class.

Comment: Ivan : all the arguments are good, I checked it, with the debug mode. My `method` needs `(string code, string namespacename, string classname,
string functionname, bool isstatic, params object[] args)` and all of thoses arguments are not null and specified. 

Amit Kumar Ghosh : I have made a `public MethodInfo CompileCode ` who needs the `System.CodeDom.Compiler;` assembly. I'm not targeting System.CodeDom.Compiler namespace but mine who is `test`. 
I am going to see if the problem is not in in `List<Compte>` or in the page I am trying to dynamically compilating who is `requestW`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching point by point everything, I found that the error was in the `requestW` class where the `"The index was off limits. It should not be negative and must be less than the size of the collection \ r \ nName parameter . StartIndex"` error was. ( After checking everything point by point, it seems that this error comes again inside of my class where I'm trying to read an Internet website.)

In this class, I have a part who goes from one side of a `<tbody` to another and after decomposition I see that the `StartIndex` value is not positive but negative, which throw an exception.

So the problem was not in the `List<Account> li = (List<Account>)method.Invoke(null, arguments);` itself but in the `method` class were my `requestW` is called and gives the Exception. 
Thank you everyone for helping me to solve my problem :)